# Application of Triangle inequality for Complex numbers

Tags: analysis

Let $ Z_1 , Z_2 ,.... , Z_{2n} $ be a distinct collection of complex numbers such that 
$$ | Z_{2i} - Z_{2i - 1} | \geq \max_{1\leq j, k \leq 2i} | Z_j - Z_k |    \quad \forall i, 1\leq i \leq n$$
Define $ c = \frac{ Z_1 + Z_2}{2}    $ .
$$\\$$
Show that, for any $ i ,   1\leq i \leq n$ , 
$$ | Z_{2i} - Z_{2i - 1} | \geq | Z_{2i} - c| $$

I figured out that any sequence of distinct complex numbers can be rearranged in such a manner, and also a list of inequalites, which are

$$  | Z_{2i} - Z_{2i - 1} | \geq | Z_{2i} - Z_1 | $$
$$  | Z_{2i} - Z_{2i - 1} | \geq | Z_{2i-1} - Z_1 | $$
$$  | Z_{2i} - Z_{2i - 1} | \geq | Z_2 - Z_{2i} | $$
$$  | Z_{2i} - Z_{2i - 1} | \geq | Z_2 - Z_{2i-1} | $$

$$  | Z_{2i} - Z_{2i - 1} | \geq | Z_2 - Z_1 | = | Z_2 - c | + | c - Z_1 | $$

I need to somehow use triangle inequality, and the above inequalities, to get the above result.
Any hints would be welcome .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this can give you any help:

$\left.\right.$

Since

$|Z_{2i}-Z_{2i-1}|\geq|Z_{2i}-Z_2|$

$|Z_{2i}-Z_{2i-1}|\geq|Z_{2i}-Z_1|$

$\left.\right.$

we have that

$\begin{align*}
2|Z_{2i}-Z_{2i-1}|&\geq|Z_{2i}-Z_2|+|Z_{2i}-Z_1|\\
&\geq|(Z_{2i}-Z_2)+(Z_{2i}-Z_1)|\qquad\quad(\text{triangle inequality})\\
&=|2Z_{2i}-(Z_1+Z_2)|\\
\end{align*}$

$\left.\right.$

then multiply $\frac12$ at both sides, we get

$\begin{align*}
|Z_{2i}-Z_{2i-1}|&\geq|\frac{2Z_{2i}-(Z_1+Z_2)}2|\\
&=|Z_{2i}-\frac{Z_1+Z_2}2|\\
&=|Z_{2i}-c|\\
\end{align*}
$